How to solve the roots of the following function numerically?
I have the following function
$$f(n) = \frac{\sqrt{n}+ \sqrt{n+ 16 (\sqrt{n}+1)}}{8} - \frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt[3]{n + \sqrt{n^2 - \frac{1}{27}}}+ \sqrt[3]{n - \sqrt{n^2 - \frac{1}{27}}}\right).$$
It is an easy exercise in calculus to show that $f(n)$ is continous for $ n > 1/\sqrt{27}$. Now, I want to find all the real solutions of
$$f(n)= 0.$$
I used the $\textit{Mathematica}$ software to find all the solutions to $f(n)= 0$, and I found that $f(n)= 0$ has three solutions and none of them is a real solutions.
However, in general, numerical algorithms are not guaranteed to find all the roots of a function. So, I can't say with $100$ percent certainity that $f(n)= 0$ has no real solutions.
However, in the case of polynomials, there exist algorithms that can find all the roots of a polynomial with very high precision. So, if I can turn the problem of finding the solutions to $f(n)= 0$ equivalent to finding the roots of a polynomial $p(n)=0$ and then
verifying which of the roots of $p(n)=0$ are actually the roots of $f(n)= 0$,
in that way, I can be certain that $\textit{Mathematica}$ didn't miss a real root of $f(n)= 0$. Can somebody give me some idea how to do it?

Is an intermediate complex, non-real answer Ok?  Like something which generates $i = \sqrt{-1}$ for intermediate steps but cancels out in the end?

Use SymPy:
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import n, t
res = minpoly((sqrt(n)+sqrt(n+16*(sqrt(n)+1)))/8 - (cbrt(n+sqrt(n*n-S(1)/27))+cbrt(n-sqrt(n*n-S(1)/27)))/2, t).subs(t, 0)
print(factor(res))

The function minpoly() in this case determines a bivariate polynomial $g(n,t)$ that is $0$ when $f(n)=t$. Substituting $t=0$ thus gives a polynomial that has to be zero for $f(n)$ to be zero:
$$-n^2(n^3+6n^2+145n-9)=0$$
None of the roots of this polynomial is greater than $\frac1{\sqrt{27}}$. This settles the matter.

Where can I read about that bivariate polynomial $g(n,t)$ that is $0$ when $f(n)=t$? This really new to me. Any resources which can describe how to construct $g(n,t)$ would be very helpful.

@SHASHANKRANJAN SymPy's documentation, of course.

Please tell me what this polynomial $g(n,t)$ is called? Where can I find how to construct $g(n,t)$ for a given $f(n)$ mathematically? $SymPy's$ documents didn't help me understand the concept of $g(n,t)$. Please help.
